# How can I expand $f(x)$ in powers of x?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

$f(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$. The closest thing I know to this would be $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$ but I don't know how to use it to write $f(x)$

Comment: On what domain, $|x|<1$, $|x|>1$?

Comment: I think it want |x|<1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+x} = \frac{2}{1+x} - \frac{1+x}{1+x}
= 2g(-x) - 1$ where $g(x) =\frac{1}{1-x}$.

You should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\frac{1-x}{1+x}=1-\frac{2x}{1+x}=1-\frac{2x}{1-(-x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Working it out in
excruciating detail:

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{1-x}{1+x}
&=\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{x}{1+x}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}x^k
-x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}x^k
-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}x^{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}x^k
-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}x^{k}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}x^k
-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}x^{k}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ((-1)^{k+1}-(-1)^{k})x^k\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ((-1)^{k+1}+(-1)^{k+1})x^k\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2(-1)^{k+1}x^k\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Smells geometric...

$$\frac{1-x}{1+x}= (1-x)\frac{1}{1-(-x)} =(1-x) \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-x)^k$$

Answer (score 0):

another way is to look at $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ as the sum of a geometric series with first term $1-x$ and ration $-x$ so that 
$$\begin{align}\frac{1-x}{1+x} &= (1-x) - x(1-x) + x^2(1-x) -x^3(1-x) + \cdots \\
&=1-2x+2x^2-2x^3 + \cdots \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you want $f(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+x}=\frac{1-(-x)^{2n}}{1-(-x)}=1+(-x)+(-x)^2+...+(-x)^{2n+1}$

> Therefore $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}u^{k}=\frac{1-u^{2n}}{1-u}$ where $u=-x$

If $n$ goes at $\infty$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{1-u}$ as long as $|u|<1$

$\Rightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}u^{2n}=0$